# How can i call below C++ function with size_t* in Objective c ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, pointers

I want to call this function **void getResult(char**, size_t*) in objective c.How can i do this please help me.
It give me below error show in image.

[image]

Comment: The error in the picture(!) is quite clear. `sizeof` doesn't give you something that has an address.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: this question might seem as a duplicate due to it's title but it has nothing to do with the post you had linked to...

Comment: @RokJarc Then its probably the OPs job to ask concise questions here. Feel free to vote for reopening.

Comment: right @RokJarc i know how to call c++ from objective c but unknown size_t* for me

Comment: Check my answer below. You might have to tweak it a bit with type casting but it should give you a kick in the right direction. You might want to add signature of your getResult function to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your getResult function expects to get second parameter by reference. You can't pass function result by reference. Assign it to actual variable first and then pass reference to that.

```
unsigned long sizeOfC = sizeof(c);
c->getResult(array1, &sizeOfC);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's worked.